# using expect script to find and return a value

Tags: regex, bash, return, expect

I have a system that, when getting `show-table[0]`, prints `0|-100|111`.

I want my expect script to receive `$row` as an argument and do the following:

1. send `show-table[$row]`
2. return the value `-100` (100 will be good too)

Here is what I've tried:

```
set row [lindex $argv 0]

expect {
    "> " {send "show-table\[$row\]\n"}
    timeout { exit 1 }
}

expect {
    "\|*\|" {}
    timeout { exit 1 }
}

exit $expect_out(0,string)
```

2 problems:

1. I didn't manage to make the script look for the argument I'm passing to it
2. I didn't manage the make the script return only -100 or 100

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your way of passing argument to the script seems to be correct.
2. After sending your command, you can use `expect -re` to match the command's output:

   set row [lindex $argv 0]

   expect {
       "> " {send "show-table[$row]\n"}
       timeout { exit 1 }
   }

   expect -re {\d+\|(-?\d+)\|\d+} { puts $expect_out(1,string) }

   expect eof

if you want to return this script output to a shell, simply `puts` from `expect` can do it, `exit` gives this script's exit status.

Comment: thanks a lot! only needed to add "\" before "[" and"]" and it did the job :)

Comment: Actually, one "\" before the first "[" is enough. :)